# How to display realtime change in server date and time every 1 Sec in php?

Tags: php, time, clock

I wrote this php code to show server date and time but I'd like to display realtime change in server date and time every 1 Sec

```
<p><?php echo "Server Time " . date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); ?> (GMT) UTC +0 UK/London</p>
```

Pls help me, thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: For example I tried this javascript code also and it works realtime but it display my pc time and not the server date and time

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function display_c(){
    var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
    mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
    }

    function display_ct() {
    var strcount
    var x = new Date()
    document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
    tt=display_c();
    }
    </script>
    <body onload=display_ct();>
    <span id='ct' ></span>

Comment: why not use the client time with out the internet traffic.

Comment: Stop using PHP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to use Javascript, something like this:

```
<body>
<p id="time"></p>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var timestamp = '<?=time();?>';
function updateTime(){
  $('#time').html(Date(timestamp));
  timestamp++;
}
$(function(){
  setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: this code display my pc date & time, not server date & time

Comment: Because JS is Front-End programming language so it takes time data from your computer, if you want server time you need to pass timestamp from php to javascript and after every second add one and format it to show date and time

Comment: I update it for you to get time and date from server

Comment: How can change the script to have only H,m,s format and something like <span style="font-size:2.5em; font-weight:bold;"> for the sze

Answer (score 1):

if you still need a real time clock that uses your server clock you could try this. im using twig `{{now|date('Y/m/d H:i:s')}}`. but you could also use php's `<?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s');?>`. its basically using `localStorage` to store the server date on `localstorage` and `setSeconds` updates the `localstorage` every 1 second , while the now variable loads the `localstorage` date and converts it to js date format. I then use the `{{now|date('Y/m/d H:i:s')}}` inside the `date` element for fallback in case localstorage is not enabled.

```
  try {
localStorage.setItem('today', new Date("{{now|date('Y/m/d H:i:s')}}");
setInterval(function clock() {
    var month = [
    "Jan", "Feb", "Marh", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Octr", "Nov", "Dec"
    ];
    var now = new Date(localStorage.getItem('today'));
    now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 1);
    localStorage.setItem('today', now);
    var G = format(now.getHours() % 12 || 12);
    var i = format(now.getMinutes());
    var s = format(now.getSeconds());
    var M = month[now.getMonth()];
    var d = format(now.getDate());
    var Y = now.getFullYear();
    function format(data) {
        return (data < 10 ? data = "0" + data : data);
    }
    $("#date").html(M + ". " + d + ", " + Y + " " + G + ":" + i + ":" + s);
    return clock;
}(), 1000);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get server time when page loaded and use javascript function to update time locally persecond. 
**HTML PAGE**

```
<script> var JS_BASE_URL = 'http://YOURSERVER/';</script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="clock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
Server Time  <span id="server_time">00:00:00</span>
</body>
```

**clock.js**

```
var url = JS_BASE_URL+'/script.php';
var _h = 0;
var _m = 0;
var _s = 0;
$.ajax({ 
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON', 
    success: function(res) {
        var timer = setInterval(serverTime,1000);
        function serverTime(){
            h = parseInt(res.hour)+_h;
            m = parseInt(res.minute)+_m;
            s = parseInt(res.second)+_s;
            if (s>59){                  
                s=s-60;
                _s=_s-60;                   
            }
            if(s==59){
                _m++;   
            }
            if (m>59){
                m=m-60;
                _m=_m-60;                   
            }
            if(m==59&&s==59){
                _h++;   
            }   
            _s++;
            $('#server_time').html(append_zero(h)+':'+append_zero(m)+':'+append_zero(s));               }
        function append_zero(n){
            if(n<10){
                return '0'+n;
            }
            else
                return n;
        }
    }
});
```

**script.php**

```
<?php
$data = array('fulldate'=>date('d-m-Y H:i:s'),
              'date'=>date('d'),
              'month'=>date('m'),
              'year'=>date('Y'),
              'hour'=>date('H'),
              'minute'=>date('i'),
              'second'=>date('s')
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

check on github: https://github.com/mdanielk/server_time

Answer (score 0):

To display changing clock showing server time by using Ajax. Create two files for this one is the file sending request and receiving data with Ajax.

### server-clock.php

develop a script where by clicking a button we can send a request to server to get the data. In the body of this file we have a button.

```
 <input type=button value=
'Get Server Time' onclick="timer_function();">
```

To this script we will add a timer to recursively call the same Ajax function in every second. This will get data from every second so we can display a changing clock showing server time.

```
function timer_function(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('AjaxFunction();',refresh)
}
```

### Timer function: timer_function()

On click of this button it trigger a function which uses a timer setTimeout. Inside this timer function it can change the refresh rate which is in milliseconds. Within this function we call our main Ajax function AjaxFunction()

```
function timer_function(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('AjaxFunction();',refresh)
}
```

At the end of AjaxFunction()   call again  timer_function() to make it recursive.

```
tt=timer_function();
```

In the main AjaxFunction()  send request to clock.php file and get the server time. This data is displayed using a div layer.

```
if(httpxml.readyState==4)
      {
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;
document.getElementById("msg").style.background='#f1f1f1';
      }
```

The second file is the simple PHP file with one line of code giving current date and time of server. clock.php

```
<?Php
echo date("d/m/y : H:i:s", time());
?>
```

download the files [here](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax-server-clock.zip)